# How to sketch the level curves of the following function

Tags: calculus, curves

Consider the function f defined by $f(x,y)=ln(x-y)$

How do I sketch the level curves for this function for the values of $k=-2,0,2$?

Comment: what is $k$ in this context?

Comment: @MiloMoses I assume are the slices on the graph of the function f? Sorry, the instructions aren't so clear on the actual question itself.

Comment: In your question it sounds as if $k$ is a single value, which can't be graphed. Could you edit your question to make what you're asking more clear?

Comment: I don’t know how to edit my question to make it more clear because this is all that is given in the actual question given to me.

Comment: In that case I cannot answer your question. Sorry!

Comment: It's alright, thanks for responding anyways.

Comment: @MiloMoses, why can't one graph $\ln(x - y) = k?$

Comment: for example, level curve for $k=0$ is $\ln(x-y)=0$, which means $x-y=1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that the level curves of $f(x, y)$ are given by $f(x, y) = k$ for some constant $k.$ Considering that $f(x, y) = \ln(x - y),$ the level curves of $f(x, y)$ are given by $\ln(x - y) = k.$ Of course, this is equivalent to $e^k = x - y,$ and this is equivalent to $y = x - e^k.$ Consequently, the level curves are the family of parallel lines $y = x - e^k$ with slope $1$ and $y-$intercept $e^k$ for each value of $k.$